# Java TimerTask wants variable to be final

Tags: java, variables, final, timertask

Anyway so im trying to make something like a chat program and someone told me to use this code to check for new messages while allowing the user to submit a message:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
     read.readChat(line);
  }
 }, 0, 1000);

 //Wait for user input
 while(true) {
     String bar = scan.next();
 }
```

Where the `read.readChat(line);` is the method which displays the messages from another file. Java tells me that `read` and `line` both have to be declared as `final`... I dont understand why especially for the "`line`" because that's a variable and I need it to change.

Additionally after I declare them as final I get this error:

```
unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                            read.readChat(salt);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see http://tech-read.com/2008/06/19/why-inner-class-can-access-only-final-variable/

Comment: alright, fair enough, so lets say I make them both final and I find a workaround that, now what about the exception being caught or declared?

Comment: @Cody: That message is saying that the line `read.readChat(salt)` throws a declared exception and you must handle it. Wrap your code in a `try-catch` block to handle the exception as your method isn't allowed to throw.

Comment: lets say I want to throw the exception, How can I got about doing that? I've tried placing it after `void run()` but more problems :(... I don't understand how to make it handle it. It doesn't throw any exceptions when its not in the `TimerTask`.. :(

Comment: @Code: If you actually want to throw it out of that method, you'll need to wrap it in a `RuntimeException` (unchecked) and throw it out of your `catch` body (so you still need to add a `try-catch` block).

Comment: @Shakedown Yah, I dont think Ill need it, at least for now, can you give me an example how to wrap it in a RuntimeException? If it's not too much to ask. Thanks

Comment: @Code `try { read.readChat(line); } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }`

Comment: ooooh THANK YOU very much, code works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second error tells you that the method `read.readChat(line);` throws a `checked` exception so you have to catch.

You cannot use local variables declared at outer class in the Anonymous  `inner` classes. Make them `final` or declare them as `fields` (instance variables).

EDIT:

```
@Override
public void run() {
  try
   {
    read.readChat(line);
   }catch(Exception ex)
   {
     ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how to make it throw the exception though. I tried to put `throws Exception` after `void run()` but that just gives me even more problems and doesn't solve this one :(.

Answer (score 1):

Cody, which thread do you want that exception to be thrown to? Right now the timer task is going to run in another thread (Timer's). So, is the timer thread that is going to deal with it in your current design. If you just want the run to re-throw an exception, you can wrap it to a RuntimeException.

```
@Override
public void run() {
  try  {
    read.readChat(line);
   }catch(RuntimeException ex)  {
     throw ex;
   }catch(Exception ex)  {
     throw new RuntimeException(ex);
   }
}
```

But, for the Timer it is not going to change anything because the run() method is the last thing the Timer thread is going to see. If you need advanced an error handling, you have to deal with it inside run(). Can you tell a bit more about what you are trying to do?